# Calculating $e^z$ for $z=\pi i + 1$ and $z=m(1-i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Calculate $e^z$ for the following points $z$:
>
> 1. $\pi i+1$
> 2. $m(i-1)$ where, $m=1,2,3...$

Work done so far:

1. $e^z=e^xe^{iy}=ee^{\pi i}$; however, the solution is $-e$. I am not sure how they got that?
2. $e^z=e^{-m}e^{mi}$

So $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{mi}}{e^m}$, I am not sure how to evaluate the limit.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't 2. be $e^m e^{-mi}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are correct! My mistake.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner the question was i-1, i mistook the question my solution is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$ We have $e^{\pi i}\cdot e^1=(-1)e=-e$

$2$ We have $e^{mi}\cdot e^{-m}=\frac {1}{e^m}(\cos m+i\sin m)$

Comment: Can you tell me how to evaluate the limit?

Comment: Well that is the $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{\cos(m)}{e^m}+\frac{i\sin(m}{e^m}\bigg]$$ Recall that $\cos \theta +\sin\theta$ is at its greatest when both parts equal $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: I am still confused, can you please elaborate. I would appreciate if you could give the answer and then explain. I am sorry for asking too many questions, but I am still unable to evaluate the limit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here $\cos(m)$ peaks at $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ while $e^m$ goes off to infinity. You're dividing a small number by one which gets infinitely large, so that result is $0$. Same for the other part.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. So $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Note that in the complex plane, the complex number $e^{mi}=\cos m+i\sin m$ lies on the unit circle. Multiplying by $\frac{1}{e^m}$ places it somewhere on a circle centered at $0$ with radius $\frac{1}{e^m}$. So the sequence is spiraling in towards $0+0i=0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to evaluate the limit?